# How to change the superscripted bibliographic citation number to a normal size number in specific cases?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, superscripts, bibliographystyle

I am using [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/manuscript-submission-template-for-the-journal-of-the-acoustic-society-of-america/zhqthzfkhhzd) journal template where all bibliographic citations are superscripted such as:

> This is true.<sup>4</sup>

With the corresponding script being:

```latex
This is true.\cite{paper_4}
```

However, I would like some bibliographic citations to appear as normal index numbers when used in a sentence such as:

> Ref. 4 shows that this is true.

Right now, using the script:

```latex
Ref. \cite{paper_4} shows that this is true.
```

I will get:

> Ref. <sup>4</sup> shows that this is true.

How can produce a normal sized citation index instead of a superscript index?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

I’m not entirely certain what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to refer back to a footnote that is defined elsewhere (doesn’t matter if it’s earlier in the text or later)? In that case you can use a \label and then use \ref to refer to:

```latex
This is some text.\footnote{\label{footlabel}%
  This footnote contains some awesome proof.
}

As shown in footnote~\ref{footlabel}, this is true.
```

Note that you will have to compile the document twice.

If what you want to do is *create* the footnote – i.e. have no conventional footnote at all but have `Ref. 4` as the only reference to the footnote (which in this scheme is really an endnote), you can do the following:

```
\def\endnotemark{\stepcounter{endnote}\theendnote}

Ref.~\endnotemark\ shows that this is true.
\endnotetext{Here is my awesome proof.}
```

The class you’re using links the footnote counter to that for endnotes, so there is no problem with the counters and you can still use `\footnote` and have it display the way you’re used to.

That said, I would still advise you don’t do this. It’s not how readers expect footnotes to work. What’s more, seeing as your journal puts out a style sheet, the editors might view that as a breach of that style. Either reference an existing footnote or, if that is not an option but the proof in question is still important enough to mention in the text, then why not put it in the main text to begin with.

Comment: Hope the `OP` meant reference entry cross link, not the `footnote` link

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes I meant cross-refences. I will amend my question to make it clearer. I have seen in publications of that journal that people do use `Ref. 4` instead of `Ref.<sup>4</sup>`. However I do not get how they achieve that since the writing guidelines only propose superscripted cross-reference indexes. Could your endnote suggestion work with `\cite{my ref}`?

Comment: No, my solution only redefines how the marker for an endnote is displayed; it doesn’t touch the cite commands. You could put `\cite{myref}` within the argument of `\endnotetext` but the example document states clearly that you should give your references within the text using `\pcite` (i.e. in parentheses). So I would only use citation commands within a footnote when giving evidence for a piece of text that’s also in the footnote.